# Random String infront of File Name

Tags: java, android

Im creating an app in android studio that grabs audio files and reads the metadata.

```
        Uri uri = resultIntent.getData();
        String[] split = uri.getPath().split("/");            

        String path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                +"/"+ split[split.length-2]
                + "/" + split[split.length-1];
```

It works fine when I try to grab from my Downloads Folder but when I attempt to grab from my SD Card, my file has a random string appended infront of it.

```
/storage/emulated/0/document/1D09-2116:song.mp3
```

What could I do to remove it?

Comment: Which is the "random" part?   Assuming that you mean the stuff before the ":", the answer is to use `split` on the filename with `":"` as the separator regex.

Comment: (The correct word for "appended infront" is "prepended".  The ford "append" *means* added at the end.  So "appended infront" literally means "added at the end at the front" ... which is self-contradictory.)

Answer (score 0):

If that random string maintains the same format everytime then you could possibly use regex alongside the replaceAll() function.

```
String str; 
String regex = ".*-\d+:";
str = str.replaceAll(regex, split[split.length-1]);
String path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
            +"/"+ split[split.length-2]
            + "/" + str;
```